# React Intl v2 unable to use <FormattedDate> with date from SQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formatjs

I've been building an demo with React and came across react-intl. I tried to use the FormattedDate component with a 'value' that is returned from an API call and is stored in 'this.state'

However the page fails to load and the console shows:
 *RangeError: Provided date is not in valid range*, the code is below.

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <IntlProvider locale='en'>
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={Login} />
          <Route path="bookings" component={Bookings} />
          <Route path="bookings/:id" component={BookingDetail} />
          <Route path="create" component={BookingCreate} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </IntlProvider>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

and in my **component's render** I Have,

```
render() {
    return (
      <FormattedDate value={new Date(this.state.booking.checkIn)}  day="numeric" month="long" year="numeric" />
    )
}
```

In the [code](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/e5b4529dae0f4f16e68a873e7de3cfd2cf907f42/src/format.js#L60) we see that the  component uses [Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/format) to produce the formatted date, but when I do the same in the **Node repl**

```
var date = '2015-10-30T23:53:28.879Z'
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(new Date(date)));

10/30/2015 //It produces the correct output
```

Any idea why this is happening? I've tried also tried assigning the bare string as the 'value', as well as  `(new Date(date.parse(this.state.booking.checkIn)`, but the all produce the range error.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue. Looking at my logs, I noticed that some libraries (momentjs in my case) return a full date with minutes divided into 100 seconds.

To take the code snippet you provided, instead of:

```
 '2015-10-30T23:53:28.879Z'
```

it returns something like:

```
 '2015-10-30T23:53:86.879Z'
```

formatjs does not accept minutes divided into more than 60 seconds (as expected).

For my needs, I do not care about the seconds, so I solved the issue by just drop the seconds from the string before passing it to formatjs.

Comment: In my case I wanted seconds, so I did `new Date(dateString)` before sending to `react-intl`